# adding effects to show and hide inside a click function

Tags: jquery

I want to add fade in/out effect into the following show/hide functions Do I add need to add another function inside `.hide(...)`?

Or would I need to add `.fadeIn(1000)` after `.hide()`?

I also wont mind using the toggle effect but whatever I tried, I couldnt make it work.

```
    $('#editPROFILE').click(function() {
        $("#B_Profile").hide();
        $('#E_Profile').show();         
    });

    $('#viewPROFILE').click(function() {
        $("#E_Profile").hide();
        $('#V_Profile').show();         
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
   $('#editPROFILE').click(function() {
      $("#B_Profile").fadeOut(1000,function(){
         $('#E_Profile').fadeIn(1000); // fade in after B has faded out
      });
    });

    $('#viewPROFILE').click(function() {

      $("#E_Profile").fadeOut(1000,function(){
         $('#V_Profile').fadeIn(1000);  // fade in after E has faded out
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

.fadeIn and .fadeOut are directly a show and hide but with the fade effect. So just use .fadeIn and .fadeOut:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/ (Display the matched elements by fading them to opaque.)
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ (Hide the matched elements by fading them to transparent.)